# How do I reinstall Ubuntu with Command line

Tags: 14.04, server

I want to clean my Server (delete everything on it) and reinstalling is the only way I know how. Are there commands to delete all files or what's the command to reinstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reinstall it, you will have to make an installer disc (or flashdrive) and install it the same way you did originally.

Alternatively you can uninstall all of the packages that you have installed. You can list them with `dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall` or `apt list --installed`.

There's also a Python script that you can use, it requires `python3-apt`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import apt

cache = apt.cache.Cache()
for package in cache:
    if (package.is_installed and
        package.candidate.priority not in ("required", "important")):
        print(package.name, end=" ")
print()
```

[Source for script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18287999).